# Android Intent ACTION_DIAL vs ACTION_VIEW which is better for dialing a number?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

Which one is better and why for showing the dial pad with entered number:

- ACTION_DIAL
- ACTION_VIEW

  ```
   button_action_view.setOnClickListener {
           val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:99986037"))
           startActivity(intent)
       }
   button_dial_view.setOnClickListener {
           val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("tel:99986037"))
           startActivity(intent)
       }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the documentation:

`ACTION_VIEW` 123 -> Display the phone dialer with the given number filled in. Note how the `VIEW` action does what is considered the most reasonable thing for a particular URI.

`ACTION_DIAL` 123 -> Display the phone dialer with the given number filled in.

So `ACTION_DIAL` is better.

Comment: Okay,....What if , the dialer application is disabled or not installed like in tablet, then in that case , which will work better ?

Comment: I think `ACTION_DIAL` still is better, `ACTION_VIEW` it depend on `Uri` and in this case, you have a specific action (calling).